# Return an new object from join using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, linqpad

I am a little bit stuck here.
I got a Database with tables for projects and versions of these projects:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public List<ProjectVersion> Versions { get; set; } = new List<ProjectVersion>();

    public Project() { }
}
```

and

```
public class ProjectVersion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Checksum { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EntryPoint> EntryPoints { get; set; } = new List<EntryPoint>();      
    public ICollection<System> Systems { get; set; } = new List<System>();

    public ProjectVersion() { }
}
```

now I want to get a specific version of a project and some detailed information

```
public static Project GetVersionByProjectId( int projectId, string version )
{
    using ( var ctx = new DatabaseContext() )
    {
        var query = 
            ctx.Projects
                .Where(p => p.Id.Equals(projectId))
                .Join(
                    ctx.Versions.Where( v => v.Version.Equals( version )),
                    p       => p.Id,
                    v       => v.ProjectId,
                    (p, v)  => new Project
                    {
                        Name     = p.Name,
                        Type     = p.Type,
                        Id       = p.Id,                                
                        Versions = new List<ProjectVersion>
                        {
                            new ProjectVersion
                            {
                                Checksum    = v.Checksum,
                                Description = v.Description,
                                Version     = v.Version ,
                                EntryPoints = new List<EntryPoint>(v.EntryPoints),
                                Systems     = new List<System>(v.Systems)                           
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
                .Select(x => x);

                var result = query.ToList();

                return result[0];
            }
        }
```

if I remove the whole

```
Versions = new List<ProjectVersion>
```

it works and I get the Project but not the Version. When I tried the LINQ in LINQPad I got following error:

```
Cannot create a query result of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UserQuery+ProjectVersion]'.
```

How can I get the Project with the requested Version?

**UPDATE**

thanks to the ideas of @RomanoZumbé and @Maritim I could solve it. Problem was different classes of the models.

```
using ( var ctx = new DatabaseContext() )
{
    var query = 
            ctx.Projects
                .Include(p => p.Versions)
                .Where(p => p.Id.Equals(projectId))
                .Select( p =>
                    new Project()
                    {
                        Id       = p.Id,
                        Name     = p.Name,
                        Type     = p.Type,
                        Versions = 
                            p.Versions
                                .Where( v => v.Version.Equals(version))
                                .Select( v =>
                                    new ProjectVersion()
                                    {
                                        Checksum    = v.Checksum,
                                        Description = v.Description,
                                        EntryPoints = 
                                            v.EntryPoints
                                                .Select( e => new EntryPoint()
                                                {           
                                                    Call = e.Call,                                                                                          
                                                    Step = e.Step                                                                                       
                                                })                                                                                  
                                                .ToList()   
                                    })
                                    .ToList()
                    })
                    .Select(x => x);

                var result = query.ToList();

                return result[0];
}
```

Comment: Are you just missing `()` behind `new List<ProjectVersion>`?

Comment: What happens if you do query.AsEnumerable() and then try to access the first occurrence?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé I am using a collection initilizer here, see [collection initilizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)

Comment: @Maritim tried it, now it says 'Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.` same when using query.ToList();

Comment: @Ben I wasn't aware, that you can leave the parenthesis out then

Comment: @Ben In that case, try v.EntryPoints.ToLIst() and v.Systems.ToLIst() instead of using List constructors with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood it correctly, and this is from top of my mind, but I think it would be easier if you used the Include(...) statement. And since you already included the project 'Versions' (which is equivalent to a JOIN statement in the database), you can do something like:

```
var query = 
        ctx.Projects
            .Include(p => p.Versions)
            .Where(p => p.Id.Equals(projectId))
            .Select(
                new Project
                {
                    Name     = p.Name,
                    Type     = p.Type,
                    Id       = p.Id,                                
                    Versions = p.Versions.Where(v => v.Version.Equals(version))
                });

return query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: this yields the same result. The Datatype of Project.Versions and Versions in DB are different, so I use `p.Versions.Where(v => v.Version.Equals(version)).Select( v => new ProjectVersion() { Id = v.Id ...}).SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: Can't you use the same class? I didn't know they were different classes. If you want some source of model mapping, try first getting your data using your db classes and then mapping to the model you want, perhaps that would be better?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure wether this is what you want to achieve, but maybe it helps.

```
            var res = (from p in ctx.Projects
                       let v = ctx.Versions.FirstOrDefault(x => p.Versions.Any(v => v.Id == x.Id))
                       where p.Id == projectId
                    select new Project
                    {
                        Name = p.Name,
                        Type = p.Type,
                        Id = p.Id,
                        Versions = new List<ProjectVersion>()
                        {
                            new ProjectVersion
                            {
                                Checksum    = v.Checksum,
                                Description = v.Description,
                                Version     = v.Version ,
                                EntryPoints = new List<EntryPoint>(v.EntryPoints),
                                Systems     = new List<System>(v.Systems)
                            }
                        }
                    });

            return res.FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: When answering a question, please make sure to point out why the approach of the OP didn't work.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm new to this stuff :-) will do.

Comment: Oh, sure! Makes sense, will do it :)